# share video in twiiter

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

Is it possible to share video in Twitter using any library? I want to share my video to twitter.
Also, can anyone give a suggestion about how to share video to Twitter?

http://venturebeat.com/2013/01/24/twitter-debuts-vine-ios-app-for-sharing-short-sweet-videos/

Vine application give functionally to share video on Twitter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you re-write "i check that vine app of twitter so that is possible in vine case i am developing same as vine but is this possible to share video in twitter ??" so it's understandable?

Comment: vine application give functionally to share video on twitter

Comment: Take a look at [Twitter cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i search many times in google, but there is no any facility to share video on Twitter. vine application is developed by twitter so that have own personal functionality to share video on twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [the uploading media new API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload-chunked), you can share video to twitter. And I have tried it, it works.

Please check this: https://github.com/liu044100/SocialVideoHelper

You just need to call this class method.

```
+(void)uploadTwitterVideo:(NSData*)videoData account:(ACAccount*)account withCompletion:(dispatch_block_t)completion;
```

Hope it can resolve your problem.